# Read up to n bytes from file

Tags: rust

The only way I know reading up to n bytes from file is [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut buffer = [0; 10];

    // read exactly 10 bytes
    f.read_exact(&mut buffer)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

What I would like to implement is: user gives a buffer and the parameter `n`, I put up to `n` bytes into that buffer.

```
fn read_n_bytes(f: &File, n: usize, dst: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    let mut buffer = [0; n]; // error here, n isn't a constant
    f.read_exact(&mut buffer);
    // concat content of buffer to dst...
}
```

How to I tell read_exact to read up to n bytes into `dst` directly?

```
fn read_n_bytes(f: &File, n: usize, dst: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    f.read_exact(dst, n);
}
```

Comment: Please see [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57203009/revisions) on your other question and try to avoid the same thing again. In this case: don't put the programming language into the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: What about `let mut v = vec![0; 100]; f.read_exact(&mut v[..n])`? Passing a `n` is IMHO very unrusty, because the slice knows how big it is. So why bothering and passing a dedicated `n` to the function?